# why is not working datepicker code

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

`<?php include('include_navigation.html');?>`

.all code is right and work but when
i have use this code 
 in my page then date-picker is not working . why it's happen plz tell me  Where the
 datepicker should appear? and also
 when i have remove this code date-picker code is working and i have not getting what
 happen so plz tell me what is wrong in here.....

date-picker code here......

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness
/jquery-ui.css" />
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

  <style>
    .datepicker{

     }
   </style>

    <script>
    $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
    });
       </script>



 html code

     <tr>
    <td>Admission Date</td>
    <td height="48">:</td>
    <td height="48"><label><input type="text" name="AD_DT" id="AD_DT"   
          class="datepicker" style="width:80px;" /></label></td>
      </tr>
```

`

Comment: Do you have an error on your console?

Comment: Where is your HTML input tag?

Comment: here is no prob in datepicker code it's worrk but when i have use
(<?php include('include_navigation.html');?>)  this code in my page datepicker not working....

Comment: it works just find, need your html

Comment: chek my edit code where is html code

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: why it happens when i have use
<?php include('include_navigation.html');?>

Comment: Your include likely contains jQuery libraries or conflicting. Remove them and it should work. This is of course only an assumption since you did not post the php here

Comment: Check your final HTML code for duplicate id (id="AD_DT")

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
});
```

Comment: this function execute when document is fully loaded. $(document).ready(

Comment: OP's `$(function() {` will work just fine. The issue is different